# Excel sheet and MS Access table Join visual studio C#

Tags: c#, sql, excel, ms-access, datatable

I Have excel sheet named as `mer_SVC` and MS Access Database table named `GIS`.I want to find the unmatched on the basis of Field `Account No`.I have generated the sql query (shown below) from design view by importing excel sheet in access table.

I am using Visual studio 2015 to show the output in datagrid view. Now using two OleDbConnection how i can generate the above query.
Query Syntax error is coming.

```
string stringconn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
                     textselect.Text + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'"; 
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(stringconn);

string stringcon = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = 
                   C:\Users\GIS\Documents\Match.accdb;";
OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(stringcon);

string path = @"F:\RAEC\RAECOEXCEL\Customer Data from CRM -
                Copy.XLSX" + " Excel 8.0";  

string query = "Select * from [mer_SVC$] IN" + path + " LEFT JOIN 
                GIS ON Account No From [mer_SVC$] IN" + "path " + " = 
                GIS.[Account No] WHERE (((GIS.[Account No]) Is Null))";

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn1);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Art the very least you need spaces after the two INs. I am off now, its 8.25 pm here, but of you haven't fixed it, I'll try in the morning

Comment: Did you tried ?

Comment: Sorry was dragged away!  Looking at it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was a bit of fun!  Firstly I do not think you can do it the way you were hoping, because the OleDbAdapter can only take one connection at a time.  However, you can achieve what you want by taking things in stages.

Firstly create two DataTables, one from Access, the other from Excel. Then turn them into a typed list.  Next use a bit of LINQ to get the missing rows.  Finally build a new DataTable from the result.

All in all it should look something like this:

```
private struct GIS
{
    public int AccountNo;
    public string AccountName;
}
private void Test()
{

    try
    {
        string xlConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\jonat\Documents\TestCSharp.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;';";
        var xlConn = new OleDbConnection(xlConnStr);

        var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [mer_SVC$]", xlConn);
        var xlDT = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(xlDT);

        List<GIS> xl = xlDT.AsEnumerable().Select(g => new GIS()
        {
            AccountNo = (int)g.Field<double>("Account No"),
            AccountName = g.Field<string>("Account Name")
        }).ToList();

        string acConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Users\jonat\Documents\PricingTools.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Persist Security Info=False;";

        var acConn = new OleDbConnection(acConnStr);
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM GIS", acConn);
        var acDT = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(acDT);

        List<GIS> ac = acDT.AsEnumerable().Select(g => new GIS()
        {
            AccountNo = g.Field<int>("Account No"),
            AccountName = g.Field<string>("Account Name")
        }).ToList();

        var missing = xl.Where(x => !ac.Any(a => a.AccountNo == x.AccountNo));
        DataTable dt = acDT.Clone();
        foreach (var m in missing)
        {
            var n = dt.NewRow();
            n["Account No"] = m.AccountNo;
            n["Account Name"] = m.AccountName;
            dt.Rows.Add(n);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception thrown; " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

A couple of things to mention.  My table in Access and my data in Excel only contained two fields, Account No and Account Name.  I presume yours has a lot more, but the technique is still the same.  Secondly although the account numbers in Excel are integers, when creating the DataTable, they are treated as doubles, so note the unboxing `(int)g.Field<double>("Account No")`, as opposed to the access version `g.Field<int>("Account No")`.

Addendum

If you use a class instead of a struct, then you can use the missing list as the source for your DataGridView (saves building the DataTable).  Like this:

```
private class GIS
{
    public int AccountNo { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
}

var missing = xl.Where(x => !ac.Any(a => a.AccountNo == x.AccountNo));
var bS = new BindingSource();
bS.DataSource = missing;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bS;
```

Comment: Dear Jonathan,i want to modify the query.In access table i have status column and want the mismatched query where Account number are equal and status =yes. I have tried using and operator but no working